# CMS: The Curious Case of "Because of"

Tags: prepositions, writing-style, conjunctions, headline-case, subordinators

The phrase "because of" is commonly thought of as a preposition; by itself, "[because](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/01/16/because_why_the_word_is_not_a_conjunction_as_dictionaries_have_it_but_instead.html)" is also considered by some to be a [subordinating conjunction](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494). The *Chicago Manual of Style* doesn't capitalize any prepositions, excepting at the start of sentences. Additionally, conjunctions are not capitalized mid-line.

How would you capitalize a heading that includes "because" or "because of" [according to](http://www.stephenfrasier.com/blog/writing/grammar/writing-style-capitalization-in-titles-headers/) the *Chicago Manual of Style*?

For example:

- Eat because You Love Food
- Run because of Your Future

Comment: If you lower-cased all phrases people have called compound prepositions, you'd have *The World according to Garp*, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: The capitalization rules say that subordinating conjunctions should be capitalized; you just lower-case coordinating conjunctions. And the word *because* is not a preposition (even if it can serve as part of a compound preposition), so it needs to be capitalized.

Comment: @WS2: the OP specifies that it's in a *heading*, so title case is acceptable (depending on the publisher's style preference).

Comment: @PeterShor The word _because_ is certainly a preposition. Geoffrey Pullum gives very good arguments why it is a preposition in the second link in the question (although I’m not entirely sold on their insistence that _that/what/how/etc._ are the only subordinator that exist). There are also very good arguments that _because of_ is not a compound preposition, but rather a preposition _because_ with a PP object headed by _of_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, here is the complete list of guidelines from *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 8.159:

> The conventions of headline style are governed mainly by emphasis and grammar. The following rules, though occasionally arbitrary, are intended primarily to facilitate the consistent styling of titles mentioned or cited in text and notes:
>
> 1. Capitalize the first and last words in titles and subtitles (but see rule 7), and capitalize all other major words (nouns, pronouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, and some conjunctions—but see rule 4).
> 2. Lowercase the articles *the*, *a*, and *an*.
> 3. Lowercase prepositions, regardless of length, except when they are used adverbially or adjectivally (*up* in *Look Up*, *down* in *Turn Down*, *on* in *The On Button*, *to* in *Come To*, etc.) or when they compose part of a Latin expression used adjectivally or adverbially (*De Facto*, *In Vitro*, etc.).
> 4. Lowercase the common coordinating conjunctions *and*, *but*, *for*, *or*, and *nor*.
> 5. Lowercase *to* not only as a preposition (rule 3) but also as part of an infinitive (*to Run*, *to Hide*, etc.), and lowercase *as* in any grammatical function.
> 6. Lowercase the part of a proper name that would be lowercased in text, such as *de* or *von*.
> 7. Lowercase the second part of a species name, such as *fulvescens* in *Acipenser fulvescens*, even if it is the last word in a title or subtitle.

---

Let's look at *eat* ***because*** *you love food* first.

*Chicago* does consider *because* on its own to be a subordinating conjunction. Per 5.200:

> A subordinating conjunction connects clauses of unequal grammatical rank. The conjunction introduces a clause that is dependent on the independent clause {follow this road **until** you reach the highway} {that squirrel is friendly **because** people feed it} {Marcus promised that he would help}. A pure subordinating conjunction has no antecedent and is not a pronoun or an adverb {take a message **if** someone calls}.

As it's not considered to be something that should be in lowercase, it should be in uppercase:

> Eat Because You Love Food

---

Now, let's look at *run* ***because of*** *your future*.

*Chicago* doesn't discuss this specifically, so I will refer to Neal Whitman's blog post ["Because as a preposition"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-as-a-preposition):

> In Standard English, the word “because” can be used two ways. One of them is to introduce a clause, as in “Aardvark was late because he was waiting for the repairman to show up.” Used this way, “because” is a subordinating conjunction. The other is to team up with “of” to form what’s called a compound preposition. For example, “Aardvark was late because of heavy traffic.”

Let's say for the sake of argument that while **because** is a subordinating conjunction, **because** ***of*** is a preposition.

But it being a preposition isn't sufficient for it to be in lowercase.

Here, I would say that **because of your future** is acting as an adverbial phrase to modify the verb *run*.

As part of an adverbial phrase, the preposition **because of** seems to meet *Chicago's* "except when they are used adverbially" criterion in its third bullet point.

[**Update**: This is based on continuing feedback that I've received through comments.]

However, in a literal sense, *Chicago* is talking about *prepositions* and not *prepositional phrases* or *compound prepositions*.

At first, I had thought that there was a difference between the following sentences, and I'd based an initial conclusion on this difference.

> It Came **from** Outer Space.
> Run **Because Of** Your Future.

Here, I had interpreted the fact that *because of* was a compound preposition, each word in that compound should be treated in the same way. And, because it was acting adverbially, each word in the compound should therefore be capitalized.

Then I was presented with the following title:

> Called on Account of Darkness

I questioned if *on account of* is exactly the same type of thing as *because of*.

[Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=AvmzBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22on%20account%20of%22%20%22compound%20preposition%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP8OHLnL3cAhVKqlQKHbLMBmIQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22on%20account%20of%22%20%22compound%20preposition%22&f=false) says that it is:

> "*On account of* is a slightly formal compound preposition meaning 'because of' (e.g. *He remained miserable and ashamed, largely on account of his appetite which continued to torment him* —A. Brookner, 1988), and first recorded in 1625.

Also, [English4Dummies](http://www.english4dummies.com/compound-prepositions/) (a perhaps less authoritative source) lists many different compound prepositions, including *because of* and *on account of*.

To maintain consistency, *all* compound prepositions need to be treated in the same way—and I've never seen the headline style of *on account of* written as *On Account Of*.

Therefore, I can only conclude that *Chicago* is talking about prepositional *words* rather than prepositional *phrases* when it talks about adverbial and adjectival usage.

Based strictly on that, and since the single word *because* is acting as a preposition within *because of*, and not acting in an adjectival way *on its own*, a strict interpretations of *Chicago* would have the correct capitalization be:

> Run because of Your Future.

Note that if I were writing the two sentences in question within the same document (or possibly even if I weren't), I would probably choose to deliberately break with this strict interpretation of *Chicago* because of consistency.

> Eat Because You Love Food.
> Run because of Your Future.

That may be a strict interpretation of *Chicago*, but a general audience would never appreciate the distinction. In order to maintain *perceived* consistency for such an audience, I would create my own style sheet with an exception for this case and instead use:

> Eat Because You Love Food.
> Eat Because of Your Future.

Nonetheless, after feedback and further consideration, I now believe that a strictly *Chicago*-based interpretation would have *Because* but *because of*.

Comment: Wrong. In *Run Because of Your Future,* the word *of* should be lowercased.

Comment: @PeterShor No, not according to the *Chicago* rule I provided. It is *Look Up* not *Look up*, etc.

Comment: Yes, the use *Look Up* is adverbial. But, for example, even though the prepositional phrase is acting adverbially in *It Came from Outer Space*, you still lower-case it because it's a preposition. For this rule, it only counts as an adverb if it's used to modify a verb and doesn't have a noun associated with it and after it.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm saying that *Because Of* is an adverbial phrase, regardless of the prepositional *of*, just as *Look Up* is an adverbial phrase, regardless of the prepositional *up*. The use of *of* after *because* gives it a specifically different function than does the use of *from* in *It Came from Outer Space*.

Comment: What is the difference between *Run Because Of Your Future* and *It Came from Outer Space*? Or would you capitalize *From*?

Comment: Am I missing something? I thought this site was about English language and usage, not particularly about fine interpretation of one (of many) style guides.

Comment: @PeterShor I have updated my answer to explain why I think there is a difference.

Comment: @JeremyC Style and punctuation, as part of usage, are also acceptable topics here.

Comment: @Jason Bassford. That was not my point: it was the the focus on a single style guide and use of the word "rules" that struck me as odd. Other style guides say different things.

Comment: @JeremyC Yes, that's certainly true. But asking about a specific style guide's use isn't really any different than asking about spelling that's particular to the US, for instance. Normally, answers should give alternate, and even competing, evidence for various things. But some questions can also be quite specific. I agree about your comment on "rules." I try not to use that word. (I just edited my answer to change that wording. I had used it only because I was quoting *Chicago*.)

Comment: If someone decided to use the phrase "called on account of darkness" as a book title, I can't imagine that Chicago would recommend handling the uppercasing/lowercasing otherwise than as _Called on Account of Darkness_. And since, to my mind, "on account of" and "because of" are functionally interchangeable. I would expect the title form of the phrase "called because of darkness" to be _Called Because of Darkness_. Any other treatment requires a foray into theory that seems unmoored from a typical reader's reasonable expectations.

Comment: @SvenYargs In that case, I would leave *of* in lowercase as the *single* prepositional word that it is. My point is that *because of* is a very specific (and unique) compound phrase (that I believe is also used adverbally). This is not about *of* but the exact collocation *because of*. (If you can point me to an authoritative source that says *on account of* is a compound preposition, you might convince me to change my mind.)

Comment: Well, there is this, from Fowler & Butterfield, [_Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage_](https://books.google.com/books?id=AvmzBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22on+account+of%22+%22compound+preposition%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP8OHLnL3cAhVKqlQKHbLMBmIQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22on%20account%20of%22%20%22compound%20preposition%22&f=false): "_On account of_ is a slightly formal compound preposition meaning 'because of' (e.g. _He remained miserable and ashamed, largely on account of his appetite which continued to torment him_ —A. Brookner, 1988), and first recorded in 1625."

Comment: @SvenYargs Excellent, thank you. You've convinced me. (I independently found something else, too, as I investigated further.) I will be changing my interpretation of this particular usage in my answer shortly...)

Comment: I agree with Peter here. You’re misunderstanding what CMoS mean by a preposition functioning adverbially: they mean it very literally. If the _preposition_ (not a prepositional phrase with the preposition as its head) is acting ‘adverbially’ (a somewhat hand-wavy term that in this case refers essentially to the particle in a phrasal verb), then you capitalise it. _Because of_ is not acting ‘adverbially’ here; the whole prepositional phrase is. But prepositional phrases are essentially **always** ‘adverbial’, so capitalising ‘adverbial’ PPs would contradict the whole point of the rule.

Comment: Since neither _because_ nor _of_ (whether you see them as a compound preposition or separate prepositions in nested PPs—the CGEL evidence for the latter is compelling, in my view) is acting adverbially on their own here, they should **both**, according to CMoS, be lowercase.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You, too, have convinced me to change my opinion and edit my answer accordingly.